# Where has this class been used?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, package

For example, I create a UserDataModel class like this:

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

import '../../../../globals/errors/exceptions.dart';
import '../../domain/entities/user_data.dart';
import '../../../../globals/utils/value_checker.dart';

class UserDataModel extends UserData {
  UserDataModel(
      {@required String fullname,
      @required String username,
      @required String token})
      : super(fullname: fullname, username: username, token: token);

  factory UserDataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserDataModel(
        fullname: json['fullname'],
        username: json['username'],
        token: json['token']);
  }

  factory UserDataModel.fromEntity(UserData userData) {
    return UserDataModel(
        fullname: userData.fullname,
        username: userData.username,
        token: userData.token);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    Map<String, dynamic> result = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    result = {
      "fullname": fullname,
      "username": username,
      "token": token,
    };

    return result;
  }
}
```

I want to know, which UserDataModel class is initialized in any file? For example, I initialize the UserDataModel class in the repository.dart file or maybe main.dart or something else. How can I know that in VSCode?

Comment: You could perform a global search (Cmd + shift + F on macOS)

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl button,

Move your mouse cursor to the Widget(class) you want to locate.

Press left click.

New tab will open containing that Widget/class.

Answer (score 0):

I have been found solution : 
1. Right click on class that I want to search for the class use
2. Select "Go to definition"
3. And I found where the class is used

[image]